# Material UI buttons not being cover by the overlay of react-burger-menu

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, hamburger-menu

I am having this weird issue with the material UI buttons not being cover by the overlay of react-burger-menu.

I tried to change the z-index of the material UI buttons, it fixes the overlay bug only if the zIndex is -1 but the buttons get totally disable and if I put a higher z-index to the menu's overlay (I even tried 1000) still the material buttons don't get cover.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a codesandbox for this?

Comment: @bertdida I have tried to set the codesandbox up by just copy pasting the code to it but all the css is a mess. I am adding the code on the post.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by applying z-index to the Navbar. As the material UI buttons were also displaying above the navbar itself.